# firefox fullscreen exits when switching xmonad workspaces

Tags: firefox, xmonad

When entering Firefox's full-screen mode (e.g. by pressing F11) inside the xmonad window manager, menu bars and address bars disappear and the browsing area is expanded throughout the window (not the screen).

This is how it should be. However, by switching xmonad's work spaces and coming back to the one containing the browser window the full-screen mode is exited.

It's very tedious to re-enter to the fill screen mode all the time.

Does someone know which mechanism causes this behavior and may how to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar behaviour of the HTML5 fullscreen viewer by using fullscreenEventHook:

```
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

xmonad $ defaultConfig
    {
    -- your configs and
    handleEventHook    = fullscreenEventHook
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for exactly the same and I finally found the answer!

The culprit is EWMH, even if you don't want Firefox' fullscreen to *actually* take the whole screen. Look at the documentation of XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops on Hackage. Here's an example from the docs:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

main = xmonad $ ewmh def{ handleEventHook =
           handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook }
```

That's all you need. Just `import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops` and don't forget to add `ewmh` before `def` wherever you defined it. You can omit the event hook if you don't want Firefox windows to take the whole screen while fullscreened. I just added those two changes and I can finally fullscreen Firefox windows without them actually covering the whole screen and they stay fullscreened when I switch workspaces!